# Find pixel coordinate of world/geographic coordinate in tile

Tags: mapbox, gis, geospatial, mercator

I'm trying to use [Mapbox Terrain RGB](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/#mapbox-terrain-rgb) to get elevation for specific points in space. I used `mercantile.tile` to get the coordinates of the tile containing my point at zoom level 15, which for `-43º, -22º` (for simplicity sake) is `12454, 18527`, then `mercantile.xy` to get the corresponding world coordinates: `-4806237.7150042495, -2621281.2257876047`.

Shouldn't the integer part of `-4806237.7150042495 / 256` (tile size) equal the x coordinate of the tile containing the point, that is, `12454`? If this calculation checked out I'd figure that I'm looking for the pixel column (x axis) corresponding to the decimal part of the result, like column 127(256 * 0,5) for 12454,5. However, the division results in -18774.366, (which is curiously close to the tile y coordinate, but it looks like a coincidence). What am I missing here?

As an alternative, I thought of using `mercantile.bounds`, assigning the first and last pixel columns to the westmost and eastmost longitudes, and finding my position with interpolation, but I wanted to check if I'm doing this the right/recommended way. I'm interested in point elevations, so everything said here goes for the Y axis as well.

Comment: I just figured everything I said applies to zoom level 0, since I'm assuming pixel coordinates = world coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got so far:

```
def correct_altitude_mode(kml):
    with open(kml, "r+") as f:
        txt = f.read()
        if re.search("(?<=<altitudeMode>)relative(?=<\/altitudeMode>)", txt):
            lat = round(float(find_with_re("latitude", txt)), 5)
            lng = round(float(find_with_re("longitude", txt)), 5)
            alt = round(float(find_with_re("altitude", txt)), 5)
        z = 15
        tile = mercantile.tile(lng, lat, z)            
        westmost, southmost, eastmost, northmost = mercantile.bounds(tile)
        pixel_column = np.interp(lng, [westmost, eastmost], [0,256])
        pixel_row = np.interp(lat, [southmost, northmost], [256, 0])
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/{z}/{tile.x}/{tile.y}.pngraw?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFydGltcGFzc29zIiwiYSI6ImNra3pmN2QxajBiYWUycW55N3E1dG1tcTEifQ.JFKSI85oP7M2gbeUTaUfQQ")
        buffer = BytesIO(response.content)
        tile_img = png.read_png_int(buffer)
        _,R,G,B = (tile_img[int(pixel_row), int(pixel_column)])
        print(tile_img[int(pixel_row), int(pixel_column)])
        height = -10000 + ((R * 256 * 256 + G * 256 + B) * 0.1)
        print(f"R:{R},G:{G},B:{B}\n{height}")
        plt.hlines(pixel_row, 0.0, 256.0, colors="r")
        plt.vlines(pixel_column, 0.0, 256.0, colors="r")
        plt.imshow(tile_img)
```

[image: The height of 880163m doesn't make sense for any point on Earth]

Comment: 880163m doesn't seem to be a reasonable height for any point on Earth